# MongoLab/PyMongo connection error

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, mlab

If I run in the shell:

```
mongo ds0219xx.mlab.com:219xx/dbname -u user -p pass
```

It works and allows me to connect to the database and pull information. But if I'm within my python application (Flask) and run this:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://user:pass@ds0219xx.mlab.com:219xx/dbname")

db = client["dbname"]

db.users.insert_one({
  "user1": "hello"
})
```

It gives me an:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

I'm pretty sure it's failing before it gets to the insert_one() call, but I'm not completely sure.

Thanks!

Edit:
By request, here is the full callback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
from app import app
File "/Users/Derek/Documents/programming/shenalum/app/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from app import views
File "/Users/Derek/Documents/programming/shenalum/app/views.py", line 4, in <module>
from data import get_posts, get_user_info
File "/Users/Derek/Documents/programming/shenalum/app/data.py", line 9, in <module>
"user1": "hello"
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 622, in insert_one
with self._socket_for_writes() as sock_info:
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 718, in _get_socket
with server.get_socket(self.__all_credentials) as sock_info:
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/server.py", line 152, in get_socket
with self.pool.get_socket(all_credentials, checkout) as sock_info:
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 541, in get_socket
sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 306, in check_auth
auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 436, in authenticate
auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 416, in _authenticate_default
return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 188, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 213, in command
read_concern)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 99, in command
helpers._check_command_response(response_doc, None, allowable_errors)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 196, in _check_command_response
raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
```

pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.

Comment: Could you include the whole traceback? That way we could be sure if it fails before the `insert_one(...)` call. Though the error is about auth and that would probably mean during `MongClient` creation :P

Comment: added that, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pymongo auth failed in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346767/pymongo-auth-failed-in-python-script)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I figured it out. You can do this from the python file and it will work:

```
connection = pymongo.MongoClient(ab123456.mlab.com, 123456)
db = connection[databasename]
db.authenticate(database_user, database_pass)
```

Comment: Please please please, mark it as correct. This is gem :)

Comment: what does this mean? like what are you trying to convey in the first line:  pymongo.MongoClient(ab123456.mlab.com, 123456). Does the port number appear as a second argument? or is the password but no username? i'm not sure how to interpret this

Comment: I guess ideally phrase that in terms of the URL OP supplied and then it'll make more sense :)

Comment: One caveat here. The characters "ab1" are probably referring to the server name, whereas "23456" would be the port, not 123456. So, heads up.

Answer (score 7):

Appending `/?authSource=admin` helped me.
Full Example:

```
uri = 'mongodb://username:password@r1.example.net:27017/?authSource=admin'

client = MongoClient(uri)
db = client.test

result = db.users.find()

for document in result:
    print(document)
```

**Version**: pymongo 3.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate after selecting the database for mongo < 4.0