# Authentication failed in connection to MongoDB Docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, authentication, docker-compose, pymongo

I deployed MongoDB using docker-compose. In `docker-compose.yml` I set user authentication

```
cis_mongodb:
    container_name: cis_mongodb
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_USER}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_PASSWORD}
```

In project root there is a file `.env` with variables `MONGO_USER` and `MONGO_PASSWORD`.
I use following code to connect to MongoDB database

```python
import pymongo

dbclient = pymongo.MongoClient(
    f'mongodb://{username}:{password}@{mongo_ip}:{mongo_port}/test',
)
```

WHen I run this code there is an error

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}
```

`username` and `password` are correct.

I also tried following urls:

```python
f'mongodb://{username}:{password}@{mongo_ip}:{mongo_port}/test'

f'mongodb://{username}:{password}@{mongo_ip}:{mongo_port}/test?authSource=admin'
```

and this way (tip from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71352629/2976612)):

```python
import urllib.parse

username = urllib.parse.quote_plus('login')
password = urllib.parse.quote_plus('password')
```

What can be the cause of the problem?

PS: version of MongoDB is 6.0.8

Comment: try connecting to the database from inside the container and see if the auth works there.

Comment: thank you for tip. I tried it and auth failed